# Dos KeyPressed Java NetBeans en un mismo textField

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola a todos estoy intentando ubicar dos KeyPressed en un mismo textField.
Actualmente el textfield esta configurado para que cuando presione Enter realice una búsqueda en la base de datos y muestre un resultado en la tabla que se ubica por debajo.
Lo que deseo es que al presionar Tab el dato ingresado en el textField se mantenga escrito y salte a la siguiente textField a la que le doy focus para que siga completando. A todo esto deseo informar el cambio de textField con un color.
El problema esta en que no me da color el textField cuando presiono tab.

```
    private void tfNombreKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){//AL DAR ENTER CON EL TECLADO APLIQUE LA ACCION DE BUSQUEDA
        tablaResultados.requestFocus();//FOCUS A LA TABLA DE ABAJO DONDE SE MOSTRARA EL RESULTADO
        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)tablaResultados.getModel();
            modelo.setRowCount(0);//ARREGLO PARA QUE EL RESULTADO SE PRESENTE PRIMERO EN LA FILA
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","xxx","xxx");//tfNombre
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();//importar java.sql.Statement./. Ejecuto sentencias en mysql
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+tfNombre.getText()+"%'");
            while(rs.next()) {//se valida si hay resultados
                do {
                String[] fila={rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8)};
                modelo.addRow(fila);
                }
                while(rs.next()); {}
                }
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consultas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }//FINAL FUNCION BUSCAR NOMBRE
    }
    else if(evt.getKeyCode()==com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent.VK_TAB);{//FUNCION TAB SALTAR Y MARCAR CON COLOR
    tfApellido.requestFocus();
    tfNombre.setBackground(Color.GREEN);    
    }
}
```

Luego de revisar el código y seguir los pasos que me dijeron implemente un **else if** para que en caso de que no presione enter el usuario sea la tecla tab.
Ahora el error que tengo es diferente, **alcanzo a escribir una sola letra y luego salta al siguiente focus que en este caso es apellido**
Que estaré haciendo mal? y perdonen no soy un programador y el codigo no esta escrito como un profesional, estoy estudiando y le pongo la mejor onda del mundo para programar este proyecto. Desde ya muchas gracias y espero contar con su ayuda.

### [image: Título]

Comment: Por qué tienes dos bucles while seguidos con la misma condición? Por qué tienes `{}` sueltos ahí después de un while?? Primero que nada, te sobra uno de los bucles, segundo, por favor, elimina los corchetes innecesarios... e **indenta correctamente tu código**, es complicado ver si todo está correcto cuando cada línea empieza en donde te sale de la gana, sin seguir un orden lógico! Por cierto, el error que te da es porque `else` ***no lleva condiciones***, su uso es `if(loQueSea){hazEsto();}else{hazLoOtro();}`, un `else` no lleva condición! tal vez quieras un `else if(otraCosa){}`!

Comment: @Benito-B agrega tú comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres "agregar una condición" al `else` debes poner un `if` luego de este, puesto que el `else` no admite la sintaxis que usas.

```
if (...) {
    // código
} else if (evt.getKeyCode()==com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
    // código
}
```

Comment: Gracias @E. Betanzos agregue el if, y no me dio mas error, pero sigue sin funcionar el cambio de color del textfield, sabras por que?